# How to add toolbars to tabview tabs inside a navigation view in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to wrap tabview in NavigationView and implement different toolbar items.For example if I have 3 tabs, 3tabs have different toolbar items.how can I achieve this?
I don't want to wrap each view in navigationView inside tabView.
I tried mentioned ways, but couldn't achieve this?

Comment: "I don't want to wrap each view in navigationView inside tabView". Why not? That is exactly what you *should* do.

Comment: A TabView shouldn’t be inside a NavigationView it is in the HIG each tab must be “mutually exclusive”.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.